# Workbench application project with documentation in eclipse

Tags: documentation, workbench, eclipse

I am trying to make a simple workbench application project in Eclipse but I can't seem to figure out how to build the documentation. I have written a package, but when I click build (under Documentation) in Application Tools I get:

```
/Users/[...]/docbuild.xml:132: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/[...]/docbuild.xml:97: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/[...]/eclipse/java-2020-12/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/440/0/.cp/MathematicaSource/DocumentationBuild/SystemFiles/ant/Build/notebook.xml:430: build failure
```

The first two lines are links to the docbuild.xml file. Do I need to modify this file?

Is there a sample workbench Application Project with Documentation that I can download and use as a guide? Is there a tutorial or book that I can consult in regards to making a proper application project together with its various ingredients such as documentation?